# Java Swing JAWS accessible JComboBox throwing NPE when items change

Tags: java, swing, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have an accessible JComboBox whose items frequently change (I perform a `jComboBox.removeAllItems();`, and then add the new items via `jComboBox.addItem(item)`).

When the items change, and the user goes to select a new item I receive the following NPE:

**NOTE** This *only* occurs when running JAWS

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.JList$AccessibleJList$AccessibleJListChild.getAccessibleSelection(JList.java:3392)
    at java.awt.Component.getAccessibleStateSet(Component.java:9624)
    at java.awt.Component$AccessibleAWTComponent.getAccessibleStateSet(Component.java:9156)
    at javax.swing.JComponent$AccessibleJComponent.getAccessibleStateSet(JComponent.java:3919)
    at javax.swing.JList$AccessibleJList$AccessibleJListChild.getAccessibleStateSet(JList.java:3301)
    at com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.getAccessibleStatesStringFromContext(AccessBridge.java:1331)
    at com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge.run(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I'm assuming this is due to the number of items in the combobox changing, but I'm not sure what's necessary to propagate the changes to the accessible context.

I have the following ActionListener on the JComboBox

```
jComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String selectedItem = (String) jComboBox.getSelectedItem();
                selectedItem = selectedItem == null ? " " : selectedItem;
                jComboBox.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(selectedItem);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you removing and adding the items in other thread different than UI thread? The actionPerformed method is called from UI thread.

Comment: No. That `Thread.run` you're seeing in the exception I'm not calling. I believe that's called by the AccessBridge, which I don't believe I have control over.

Comment: Ok, but you can protect the modification of combobox through synchronization. I've write in a answer.

Comment: Even synchronizing the access to the JComboBox, the exception still occurs.